# How to filter text from text from image with python?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

[image]I can extract text from an image in pdf.
The text that is extracted from the image is like this:

```
Koopliedenweg 38\nDeb. nr. : 108636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum : 19-11-21\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nOrder number : 76372 Loading date : 15-11-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK46\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\n566 Ananas 
Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I € 7,00 € 3.962,00\n706 Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I € 4,68 € 3.304,08\n598 Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 3.767,40\nOrder number : 76462 Loading date : 18-11-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date
```

But now I want to return some specific text.
So in this case I am looking for the string: Appels Royal Gala 13kg
So I try it like this:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi

pdfFile = wi(filename = "C:\\Users\\engel\\Documents\\python\\docs\\fixedPDF.pdf", resolution = 300)
image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')

imageBlobs = []


for img in image.sequence:
    imgPage = wi(image = img)
    imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

extract = []

for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang = 'eng')
    extract.append(text)
    interested_string = 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg'
    line = [l[1] for l in extract if 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg' in l[1]]
print(line)
```

But the result is an empty array: `[]`

So what I have to change?

Thank you

oke, if I do this:

```
    line = [l[1] for l in extract if 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg' in l]
```

I get this as output:

```
['=']
```

and then if I do it like this:

```
for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
    extract.append(text)
    interested_string = 'Verdi Import Schoolfruit'   
line = [l[1] for l in extract if 'It was the best of' in l]

print(line)
```

then the result is:

```
['t']
```

oke, If I do this:

```
line = [l for l in extract if 'It was the best of' in l]

print(extract)

print(line)
```

then I get this as output:

```
['It was the best of\ntimes, it was the worst\nof times, it was the age\nof wisdom, it was the\nage of foolishness...\n\x0c']
['It was the best of\ntimes, it was the worst\nof times, it was the age\nof wisdom, it was the\nage of foolishness...\n\x0c']
```

Comment: if you know the exact expression that you are looking for (i.e:`Appels Royal Gala 13kg`), then you may find [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
line = [l[1] for l in extract if 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg' in l[1]]
```

You are looking for your string `in l[1]` but `l[1]` is only the second letter of your sentence, so maybe:

```
line = [l[1] for l in extract if 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg' in l]
```

Comment: There is no *=* in the string you have put in the beginning, are you sure you are working on this one ?

Comment: See the updated post

Comment: By taking `l[1]`, you are selecting the letter at index 1 on your `text`string, which is the second letter. For the sentence "It was the best ...", this letter is `t`.  What do you want to find exactly in the `text` if you find the substring you want ? ?

Comment: But how thus selecting a whole string from begin to end? It was the best

Comment: Try `[l for l in extract if 'The string you want to find' in l]`